# I wanna create a music list in react. How can I create it?

Tags: reactjs, audio, audio-player

I have created a Play Pause button in react but I can manage only a single song. I wanna List more songs and want to play and pause. I want to play one song at a time.

I have tried this using audio.

This is My render function -

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button getsrc="http://streaming.tdiradio.com:8000/house.mp3" onClick={this.togglePlay}>{this.state.play ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}</button><br /><br />
                <button getsrc="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" onClick={this.togglePlay}>{this.state.play ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}</button>
                <button getsrc="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3" onClick={this.togglePlay}>{this.state.play ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}</button>
                <button getsrc="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3" onClick={this.togglePlay}>{this.state.play ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

This is my constructor and audio function -

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            play: false
        }
    }

    audio = new Audio("http://streaming.tdiradio.com:8000/house.mp3")

    togglePlay = () => {
        this.setState({ play: !this.state.play }, () => {
            this.state.play ? this.audio.play() : this.audio.pause();
        });
    }
```

How can I play my one song at a time. And display the played song information as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code

```
state = {
    play: false,
    currentSong: null,
  };

  audio = null;

  togglePlay = (e) => {
    const song = e.target.id;
    if (this.state.currentSong === song) {
      this.state.play ? this.audio.pause() : this.audio.play();
      this.setState({ play: !this.state.play });
    } else {

      if (this.audio) {
        this.audio.pause();
      }

      this.setState({
        currentSong: song,
        play: true,
      });
      this.audio = new Audio(song);
      this.audio.play();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const songs = [
      'http://streaming.tdiradio.com:8000/house.mp3',
      'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3',
      'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3',
      'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3',
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        {songs.map(song =>
          <div>
            <button id={song} key={song} onClick={this.togglePlay}>
              {this.state.currentSong !== song || !this.state.play ? 'Play' : 'Pause'}
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```